# Add folder option missing at directory level. Still able to add folder on desktop

Tags: gnome

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 and Gnome 3.36.8. I ran Clam AV and removed viruses. Since deleting viruses, now I can only add new folders at the desktop level and cannot drag and drop the folder where I intended it to be. Is this an issue with Gnome, or somehow connected with removing the viruses? How can I restore this missing drop down so that I can create folders where I need them to be again?

Comment: What have you removed exactly?

Comment: I removed 1 worm, 1 dropper, and several trojans

Comment: You apparently removed more than only viruses.

Comment: Apparently.... now, how do i fix it? I wonder how i made that  happen.